# Warsow Crash all the time (Xubuntu 16.04)

Tags: xubuntu, games

I installed last version of Warsow (2.1) and the old (2.0) in a Xubuntu 16.04 system (Toshiba Satellite pro C850 laptop 64bits -1,8 GB RAM-), but when I run the start script, then in two or three minutes it crashes.

It doesn't matter if it's in the main menu or in a game...

I don't have any Error code or anything like that.

I tried to run it from the terminal but there are no Error messages.

output of `sudo lshw -C video` :

`*-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:27 memory:c2000000-c23fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:3000(size=64)`

log of the old version:

```
Hostname: (myname)
IP: ---------
IP: ---------
IP: ---------
Loading Steam module... Success.
------- angel script initialization -------
Loading angelwrap module.
Initializing Angel Script
Initialization of angelwrap successful
------------------------------------
Game running at 62 fps. Server transmit at 20 pps
Opening TCP/IP socket: *:44444
Web server started on 0.0.0.0:44444
Opening TCP/IPv6 socket: *:44444
Web server started on [0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000]:44444
Console initialized.
Steam initialization failed.
Loaded libfreetype.so.6
Loading refresh module ref_gl... 
Initializing OpenGL display
...setting mode: 1366 768 FS
GL PFD: color(24-bits) Z(24-bit) stencil(8-bits)

GL_VENDOR: Intel Open Source Technology Center
GL_RENDERER: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile 
GL_VERSION: 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0
GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION: 1.30
GL_EXTENSIONS: GL_ARB_multisample GL_EXT_abgr GL_EXT_bgra GL_EXT_blend_color GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_blend_subtract GL_EXT_copy_texture GL_EXT_polygon_offset GL_EXT_subtexture GL_EXT_texture_object GL_EXT_vertex_array GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array GL_EXT_texture GL_EXT_texture3D GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip GL_ARB_point_parameters GL_EXT_draw_range_elements GL_EXT_packed_pixels GL_EXT_point_parameters GL_EXT_rescale_normal GL_EXT_separate_specular_color GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp GL_SGIS_texture_lod GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB GL_ARB_multitexture GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1 GL_ARB_texture_cube_map GL_ARB_texture_env_add GL_ARB_transpose_matrix GL_EXT_blend_func_separate GL_EXT_fog_coord GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays GL_EXT_secondary_color GL_EXT_texture_env_add GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias GL_INGR_blend_func_separate GL_NV_blend_square GL_NV_light_max_exponent GL_NV_texgen_reflection GL_NV_texture_env_combine4 GL_S3_s3tc GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp GL_ARB_texture_compression GL_EXT_framebuffer_object GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc GL_EXT_texture_env_combine GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3 GL_MESA_window_pos GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil GL_NV_texture_rectangle GL_ARB_depth_texture GL_ARB_occlusion_query GL_ARB_shadow GL_ARB_texture_env_combine GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3 GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_ARB_window_pos GL_EXT_stencil_two_side GL_EXT_texture_cube_map GL_NV_depth_clamp GL_APPLE_packed_pixels GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object GL_ARB_draw_buffers GL_ARB_fragment_program GL_ARB_fragment_shader GL_ARB_shader_objects GL_ARB_vertex_program GL_ARB_vertex_shader GL_ATI_draw_buffers GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3 GL_ATI_texture_float GL_EXT_shadow_funcs GL_EXT_stencil_wrap GL_MESA_pack_invert GL_NV_primitive_restart GL_ARB_depth_clamp GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow GL_ARB_half_float_pixel GL_ARB_occlusion_query2 GL_ARB_point_sprite GL_ARB_shading_language_100 GL_ARB_sync GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate GL_OES_read_format GL_ARB_color_buffer_float GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc GL_ARB_texture_float GL_ARB_texture_rectangle GL_EXT_packed_float GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1 GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc GL_EXT_texture_rectangle GL_EXT_texture_sRGB GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent GL_ARB_framebuffer_object GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil GL_APPLE_object_purgeable GL_ARB_vertex_array_object GL_ATI_separate_stencil GL_EXT_draw_buffers2 GL_EXT_draw_instanced GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters GL_EXT_texture_array GL_EXT_texture_integer GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_timer_query GL_OES_EGL_image GL_AMD_performance_monitor GL_ARB_copy_buffer GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float GL_ARB_draw_instanced GL_ARB_half_float_vertex GL_ARB_instanced_arrays GL_ARB_map_buffer_range GL_ARB_texture_rg GL_ARB_texture_swizzle GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra GL_EXT_texture_swizzle GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra GL_NV_conditional_render GL_AMD_conservative_depth GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility GL_ARB_blend_func_extended GL_ARB_debug_output GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions GL_ARB_provoking_vertex GL_ARB_sample_shading GL_ARB_sampler_objects GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array GL_ARB_texture_gather GL_ARB_texture_multisample GL_ARB_texture_query_lod GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev GL_EXT_provoking_vertex GL_EXT_texture_snorm GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba GL_NV_texture_barrier GL_ARB_get_program_binary GL_ARB_robustness GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc GL_ARB_timer_query GL_ARB_transform_feedback2 GL_ARB_transform_feedback3 GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3 GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5 GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage GL_ARB_conservative_depth GL_ARB_internalformat_query GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack GL_ARB_shading_language_packing GL_ARB_texture_storage GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled GL_EXT_transform_feedback GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object GL_ARB_copy_image GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location GL_ARB_framebuffer_no_attachments GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata GL_ARB_program_interface_query GL_ARB_shader_image_size GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object GL_ARB_texture_query_levels GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample GL_ARB_texture_view GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding GL_KHR_debug GL_ARB_buffer_storage GL_ARB_clear_texture GL_ARB_multi_bind GL_ARB_seamless_cubemap_per_texture GL_ARB_shader_draw_parameters GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix GL_INTEL_performance_query GL_ARB_clip_control GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted GL_ARB_derivative_control GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image GL_ARB_pipeline_statistics_query GL_ARB_shader_texture_image_samples GL_ARB_texture_barrier GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp GL_KHR_context_flush_control GL_ARB_shader_clock GL_EXT_shader_samples_identical 
GLXW_EXTENSIONS: none
GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS: 8
GL_MAX_CUBE_MAP_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
GL_MAX_3D_TEXTURE_SIZE: 2048
GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS: 2048
GL_MAX_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY: 16
GL_MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE: 8192
GL_MAX_VARYING_FLOATS: 128
GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS: 16384
GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS: 16
GL_MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS: 16384

mode: 1366x768, fullscreen
picmip: 1
texturemode: GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST
anisotropic filtering: 0
vertical sync: disabled
multithreading: enabled
multitexture: enabled
vertex_buffer_object: enabled
vertex_shader: enabled
fragment_shader: enabled
shader_objects: enabled
shading_language_100: enabled
GLSL: enabled
GLSL_core: enabled
GLSL130: enabled
draw_range_elements: enabled
framebuffer_object: enabled
framebuffer_blit: enabled
texture_compression: enabled
texture_edge_clamp: enabled
texture_cube_map: enabled
depth_texture: enabled
shadow: enabled
texture_non_power_of_two: enabled
draw_instanced: enabled
instanced_arrays: enabled
half_float_vertex: enabled
get_program_binary: enabled
ES3_compatibility: enabled
blend_func_separate: enabled
texture3D: enabled
texture_array: enabled
packed_depth_stencil: enabled
texture_lod: enabled
gpu_shader5: disabled
gpu_memory_info: disabled
meminfo: disabled
texture_filter_anisotropic: enabled
bgra: enabled

Video memory information:
not available
Loaded libjpeg.so.8
Loaded libpng12.so.0
Initializing Shaders:
...loading 'scripts/36.shader'
...loading 'scripts/alley.shader'
...loading 'scripts/ammobox.shader'
...loading 'scripts/baxandall.shader'
...loading 'scripts/bigvic.shader'
...loading 'scripts/billboard.shader'
...loading 'scripts/blx.shader'
...loading 'scripts/blx_ca.shader'
...loading 'scripts/blx_grey.shader'
...loading 'scripts/blx_houses.shader'
...loading 'scripts/blx_tech2.shader'
...loading 'scripts/blx_wt3.shader'
...loading 'scripts/blx_wt3_vertex.shader'
...loading 'scripts/blxbis.shader'
...loading 'scripts/bobot.shader'
...loading 'scripts/bomb.shader'
...loading 'scripts/bomb_gfx.shader'
...loading 'scripts/boqu.shader'
...loading 'scripts/bricks_vertex.shader'
...loading 'scripts/budndumby.shader'
...loading 'scripts/cha0swsw.shader'
...loading 'scripts/cleansurface.shader'
...loading 'scripts/cleansurface_vertex.shader'
...loading 'scripts/common.shader'
...loading 'scripts/concrete.shader'
...loading 'scripts/concretestrike.shader'
...loading 'scripts/courtyard.shader'
...loading 'scripts/ctftactics_icons.shader'
...loading 'scripts/decals.shader'
...loading 'scripts/deleo.shader'
...loading 'scripts/depot.shader'
...loading 'scripts/effects.shader'
...loading 'scripts/etrtex.shader'
...loading 'scripts/extra.shader'
...loading 'scripts/exwsw.shader'
...loading 'scripts/exwsw_vertex.shader'
...loading 'scripts/factory.shader'
...loading 'scripts/format.shader'
...loading 'scripts/gfx.shader'
...loading 'scripts/glass.shader'
...loading 'scripts/grates.shader'
...loading 'scripts/grates_vertex.shader'
...loading 'scripts/hazelh.shader'
...loading 'scripts/headicons.shader'
...loading 'scripts/hexagons.shader'
...loading 'scripts/hud.shader'
...loading 'scripts/jewels.shader'
...loading 'scripts/legacy.shader'
...loading 'scripts/lights.shader'
...loading 'scripts/mapmodels.shader'
...loading 'scripts/mapobjects.shader'
...loading 'scripts/matchmaker.shader'
...loading 'scripts/metal.shader'
...loading 'scripts/metal_vertex.shader'
...loading 'scripts/models.shader'
...loading 'scripts/monada.shader'
...loading 'scripts/nate.shader'
...loading 'scripts/nature.shader'
...loading 'scripts/neon.shader'
...loading 'scripts/noir.shader'
...loading 'scripts/padpork.shader'
...loading 'scripts/plastic.shader'
...loading 'scripts/plastic_vertex.shader'
...loading 'scripts/polybeams.shader'
...loading 'scripts/quake.shader'
...loading 'scripts/reactors.shader'
...loading 'scripts/respawnindicators.shader'
...loading 'scripts/reviver.shader'
...loading 'scripts/runner.shader'
...loading 'scripts/russus.shader'
...loading 'scripts/scifi_interior.shader'
...loading 'scripts/shepas.shader'
...loading 'scripts/silverclaw.shader'
...loading 'scripts/sky.shader'
...loading 'scripts/skyportals.shader'
...loading 'scripts/solidfake.shader'
...loading 'scripts/starsky.shader'
...loading 'scripts/supersymmetry.shader'
...loading 'scripts/terrain.shader'
...loading 'scripts/tiles.shader'
...loading 'scripts/turret.shader'
...loading 'scripts/tutorial.shader'
...loading 'scripts/ui.shader'
...loading 'scripts/ui_porkui.shader'
...loading 'scripts/viciious.shader'
...loading 'scripts/wctf4.shader'
...loading 'scripts/wdm1.shader'
...loading 'scripts/wdm11.shader'
...loading 'scripts/wdm17.shader'
...loading 'scripts/wdm4.shader'
...loading 'scripts/wdm6.shader'
...loading 'scripts/wdm7.shader'
...loading 'scripts/wdm9.shader'
...loading 'scripts/window.shader'
...loading 'scripts/wood.shader'
...loading 'scripts/wood_vertex.shader'
...loading 'scripts/world.shader'
...loading 'scripts/wsw_cave1.shader'
...loading 'scripts/wsw_city1.shader'
...loading 'scripts/wsw_flareshalos.shader'
...loading 'scripts/zone_neutre.shader'
--------------------------------------
------- sound initialization -------
Loading sound module: qf
SDL Audio driver initializing...
Calling SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_AUDIO)...
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_AUDIO) passed.
SDL audio driver is "pulseaudio"
Format we requested from SDL audio device:
Format: AUDIO_S16LSB
Freq: 44100
Samples: 1024
Channels: 2

Format we actually got:
Format: AUDIO_S16LSB
Freq: 44100
Samples: 512
Channels: 2

Starting SDL audio callback...
SDL audio initialized.
Sound sampling rate: 44100
Loaded libvorbisfile.so.3
Initialization of qf successful
------------------------------------
Loaded font 'Droid Sans Bold' from 'DroidSans-Bold.ttf'
Loaded font 'Droid Sans Regular' from 'DroidSans.ttf'
LoHostname: jeroqui
IP: 127.0.1.1
IP: 127.0.1.1
IP: 127.0.1.1
Loading Steam module... Success.
------- angel script initialization -------
Loading angelwrap module.
Initializing Angel Script
Initialization of angelwrap successful
------------------------------------
Game running at 62 fps. Server transmit at 20 pps
Opening TCP/IP socket: *:44444
Web server started on 0.0.0.0:44444
Opening TCP/IPv6 socket: *:44444
Web server started on [0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000]:44444
Console initialized.
Steam initialization failed.
Loaded libfreetype.so.6
Loading refresh module ref_gl... 
Initializing OpenGL display
...setting mode: 1366 768 FS
GL PFD: color(24-bits) Z(24-bit) stencil(8-bits)

GL_VENDOR: Intel Open Source Technology Center
GL_RENDERER: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile 
GL_VERSION: 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0
GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION: 1.30
GL_EXTENSIONS: GL_ARB_multisample GL_EXT_abgr GL_EXT_bgra GL_EXT_blend_color GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_blend_subtract GL_EXT_copy_texture GL_EXT_polygon_offset GL_EXT_subtexture GL_EXT_texture_object GL_EXT_vertex_array GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array GL_EXT_texture GL_EXT_texture3D GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip GL_ARB_point_parameters GL_EXT_draw_range_elements GL_EXT_packed_pixels GL_EXT_point_parameters GL_EXT_rescale_normal GL_EXT_separate_specular_color GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp GL_SGIS_texture_lod GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB GL_ARB_multitexture GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1 GL_ARB_texture_cube_map GL_ARB_texture_env_add GL_ARB_transpose_matrix GL_EXT_blend_func_separate GL_EXT_fog_coord GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays GL_EXT_secondary_color GL_EXT_texture_env_add GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias GL_INGR_blend_func_separate GL_NV_blend_square GL_NV_light_max_exponent GL_NV_texgen_reflection GL_NV_texture_env_combine4 GL_S3_s3tc GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp GL_ARB_texture_compression GL_EXT_framebuffer_object GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc GL_EXT_texture_env_combine GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3 GL_MESA_window_pos GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil GL_NV_texture_rectangle GL_ARB_depth_texture GL_ARB_occlusion_query GL_ARB_shadow GL_ARB_texture_env_combine GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3 GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_ARB_window_pos GL_EXT_stencil_two_side GL_EXT_texture_cube_map GL_NV_depth_clamp GL_APPLE_packed_pixels GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object GL_ARB_draw_buffers GL_ARB_fragment_program GL_ARB_fragment_shader GL_ARB_shader_objects GL_ARB_vertex_program GL_ARB_vertex_shader GL_ATI_draw_buffers GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3 GL_ATI_texture_float GL_EXT_shadow_funcs GL_EXT_stencil_wrap GL_MESA_pack_invert GL_NV_primitive_restart GL_ARB_depth_clamp GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow GL_ARB_half_float_pixel GL_ARB_occlusion_query2 GL_ARB_point_sprite GL_ARB_shading_language_100 GL_ARB_sync GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate GL_OES_read_format GL_ARB_color_buffer_float GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc GL_ARB_texture_float GL_ARB_texture_rectangle GL_EXT_packed_float GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1 GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc GL_EXT_texture_rectangle GL_EXT_texture_sRGB GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent GL_ARB_framebuffer_object GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil GL_APPLE_object_purgeable GL_ARB_vertex_array_object GL_ATI_separate_stencil GL_EXT_draw_buffers2 GL_EXT_draw_instanced GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters GL_EXT_texture_array GL_EXT_texture_integer GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_timer_query GL_OES_EGL_image GL_AMD_performance_monitor GL_ARB_copy_buffer GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float GL_ARB_draw_instanced GL_ARB_half_float_vertex GL_ARB_instanced_arrays GL_ARB_map_buffer_range GL_ARB_texture_rg GL_ARB_texture_swizzle GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra GL_EXT_texture_swizzle GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra GL_NV_conditional_render GL_AMD_conservative_depth GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility GL_ARB_blend_func_extended GL_ARB_debug_output GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions GL_ARB_provoking_vertex GL_ARB_sample_shading GL_ARB_sampler_objects GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array GL_ARB_texture_gather GL_ARB_texture_multisample GL_ARB_texture_query_lod GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev GL_EXT_provoking_vertex GL_EXT_texture_snorm GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba GL_NV_texture_barrier GL_ARB_get_program_binary GL_ARB_robustness GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc GL_ARB_timer_query GL_ARB_transform_feedback2 GL_ARB_transform_feedback3 GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3 GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5 GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage GL_ARB_conservative_depth GL_ARB_internalformat_query GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack GL_ARB_shading_language_packing GL_ARB_texture_storage GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled GL_EXT_transform_feedback GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object GL_ARB_copy_image GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location GL_ARB_framebuffer_no_attachments GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata GL_ARB_program_interface_query GL_ARB_shader_image_size GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object GL_ARB_texture_query_levels GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample GL_ARB_texture_view GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding GL_KHR_debug GL_ARB_buffer_storage GL_ARB_clear_texture GL_ARB_multi_bind GL_ARB_seamless_cubemap_per_texture GL_ARB_shader_draw_parameters GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix GL_INTEL_performance_query GL_ARB_clip_control GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted GL_ARB_derivative_control GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image GL_ARB_pipeline_statistics_query GL_ARB_shader_texture_image_samples GL_ARB_texture_barrier GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp GL_KHR_context_flush_control GL_ARB_shader_clock GL_EXT_shader_samples_identical 
GLXW_EXTENSIONS: none
GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS: 8
GL_MAX_CUBE_MAP_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
GL_MAX_3D_TEXTURE_SIZE: 2048
GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS: 2048
GL_MAX_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY: 16
GL_MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE: 8192
GL_MAX_VARYING_FLOATS: 128
GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS: 16384
GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS: 16
GL_MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS: 16384

mode: 1366x768, fullscreen
picmip: 1
texturemode: GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST
anisotropic filtering: 0
vertical sync: disabled
multithreading: enabled
multitexture: enabled
vertex_buffer_object: enabled
vertex_shader: enabled
fragment_shader: enabled
shader_objects: enabled
shading_language_100: enabled
GLSL: enabled
GLSL_core: enabled
GLSL130: enabled
draw_range_elements: enabled
framebuffer_object: enabled
framebuffer_blit: enabled
texture_compression: enabled
texture_edge_clamp: enabled
texture_cube_map: enabled
depth_texture: enabled
shadow: enabled
texture_non_power_of_two: enabled
draw_instanced: enabled
instanced_arrays: enabled
half_float_vertex: enabled
get_program_binary: enabled
ES3_compatibility: enabled
blend_func_separate: enabled
texture3D: enabled
texture_array: enabled
packed_depth_stencil: enabled
texture_lod: enabled
gpu_shader5: disabled
gpu_memory_info: disabled
meminfo: disabled
texture_filter_anisotropic: enabled
bgra: enabled

Video memory information:
not available
Loaded libjpeg.so.8
Loaded libpng12.so.0
Initializing Shaders:
...loading 'scripts/36.shader'
...loading 'scripts/alley.shader'
...loading 'scripts/ammobox.shader'
...loading 'scripts/baxandall.shader'
...loading 'scripts/bigvic.shader'
...loading 'scripts/billboard.shader'
...loading 'scripts/blx.shader'
...loading 'scripts/blx_ca.shader'
...loading 'scripts/blx_grey.shader'
...loading 'scripts/blx_houses.shader'
...loading 'scripts/blx_tech2.shader'
...loading 'scripts/blx_wt3.shader'
...loading 'scripts/blx_wt3_vertex.shader'
...loading 'scripts/blxbis.shader'
...loading 'scripts/bobot.shader'
...loading 'scripts/bomb.shader'
...loading 'scripts/bomb_gfx.shader'
...loading 'scripts/boqu.shader'
...loading 'scripts/bricks_vertex.shader'
...loading 'scripts/budndumby.shader'
...loading 'scripts/cha0swsw.shader'
...loading 'scripts/cleansurface.shader'
...loading 'scripts/cleansurface_vertex.shader'
...loading 'scripts/common.shader'
...loading 'scripts/concrete.shader'
...loading 'scripts/concretestrike.shader'
...loading 'scripts/courtyard.shader'
...loading 'scripts/ctftactics_icons.shader'
...loading 'scripts/decals.shader'
...loading 'scripts/deleo.shader'
...loading 'scripts/depot.shader'
...loading 'scripts/effects.shader'
...loading 'scripts/etrtex.shader'
...loading 'scripts/extra.shader'
...loading 'scripts/exwsw.shader'
...loading 'scripts/exwsw_vertex.shader'
...loading 'scripts/factory.shader'
...loading 'scripts/format.shader'
...loading 'scripts/gfx.shader'
...loading 'scripts/glass.shader'
...loading 'scripts/grates.shader'
...loading 'scripts/grates_vertex.shader'
...loading 'scripts/hazelh.shader'
...loading 'scripts/headicons.shader'
...loading 'scripts/hexagons.shader'
...loading 'scripts/hud.shader'
...loading 'scripts/jewels.shader'
...loading 'scripts/legacy.shader'
...loading 'scripts/lights.shader'
...loading 'scripts/mapmodels.shader'
...loading 'scripts/mapobjects.shader'
...loading 'scripts/matchmaker.shader'
...loading 'scripts/metal.shader'
...loading 'scripts/metal_vertex.shader'
...loading 'scripts/models.shader'
...loading 'scripts/monada.shader'
...loading 'scripts/nate.shader'
...loading 'scripts/nature.shader'
...loading 'scripts/neon.shader'
...loading 'scripts/noir.shader'
...loading 'scripts/padpork.shader'
...loading 'scripts/plastic.shader'
...loading 'scripts/plastic_vertex.shader'
...loading 'scripts/polybeams.shader'
...loading 'scripts/quake.shader'
...loading 'scripts/reactors.shader'
...loading 'scripts/respawnindicators.shader'
...loading 'scripts/reviver.shader'
...loading 'scripts/runner.shader'
...loading 'scripts/russus.shader'
...loading 'scripts/scifi_interior.shader'
...loading 'scripts/shepas.shader'
...loading 'scripts/silverclaw.shader'
...loading 'scripts/sky.shader'
...loading 'scripts/skyportals.shader'
...loading 'scripts/solidfake.shader'
...loading 'scripts/starsky.shader'
...loading 'scripts/supersymmetry.shader'
...loading 'scripts/terrain.shader'
...loading 'scripts/tiles.shader'
...loading 'scripts/turret.shader'
...loading 'scripts/tutorial.shader'
...loading 'scripts/ui.shader'
...loading 'scripts/ui_porkui.shader'
...loading 'scripts/viciious.shader'
...loading 'scripts/wctf4.shader'
...loading 'scripts/wdm1.shader'
...loading 'scripts/wdm11.shader'
...loading 'scripts/wdm17.shader'
...loading 'scripts/wdm4.shader'
...loading 'scripts/wdm6.shader'
...loading 'scripts/wdm7.shader'
...loading 'scripts/wdm9.shader'
...loading 'scripts/window.shader'
...loading 'scripts/wood.shader'
...loading 'scripts/wood_vertex.shader'
...loading 'scripts/world.shader'
...loading 'scripts/wsw_cave1.shader'
...loading 'scripts/wsw_city1.shader'
...loading 'scripts/wsw_flareshalos.shader'
...loading 'scripts/zone_neutre.shader'
--------------------------------------
------- sound initialization -------
Loading sound module: qf
SDL Audio driver initializing...
Calling SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_AUDIO)...
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_AUDIO) passed.
SDL audio driver is "pulseaudio"
Format we requested from SDL audio device:
Format: AUDIO_S16LSB
Freq: 44100
Samples: 1024
Channels: 2

Format we actually got:
Format: AUDIO_S16LSB
Freq: 44100
Samples: 512
Channels: 2

Starting SDL audio callback...
SDL audio initialized.
Sound sampling rate: 44100
Loaded libvorbisfile.so.3
Initialization of qf successful
------------------------------------
Loaded font 'Droid Sans Bold' from 'DroidSans-Bold.ttf'
Loaded font 'Droid Sans Regular' from 'DroidSans.ttf'
Lo
```

Comment: Are you using Wine? If so, which version?

Comment: Does any other game crash? Which graphic card do you have? Please add the output of `sudo lshw -C video` to your question.

Comment: No, I'm not using Wine, I'm using the official Linux version for Ubuntu.

No other game crash...

Comment: There must be a log file somewhere (considering the game is based in Quake II engine). According to a question in Warsow forum, you can get a log by running the game with "+set logconsole game.log" as arguments. Also, have you tried running the game with: `warsow +exec profiles/low`

Comment: I cant find the ".log" file.

Comment: Go to home folder, press Ctrl+H to see invisible files and folders, and see inside .warsow folder. This is where configuration files of the game must be. Alternatively, in the arguments of the game set the absolute path of the log file, like `/home/username/game.log`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42827/discussion-between-luchonacho-and-ovni-jeroqui).

Comment: You have not added the error log. Did you solve the problem?

Comment: No, I only have the log file for the old version.

Comment: Can you add the log to the question please?